# How does NFC Task Launcher toggle Power Saving and how can I get Tasker to do it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, tasker, nfc

So I've noticed that NFC Task Launcher can toggle the Power Saving mode for the Galaxy s3.

Obviously then, this is not a secure setting that requires root access (eg. turning GPS on / off).

So is it possible to automate this (the turning on and off of power saving mode) in Tasker (without rooting my phone)?  I've tried to use the Load App functionality but the most I can do is open up the Power Saving control panel.

I'm thinking the toggle is most likely an Intent that NFC Task launcher is calling but I don't know what the intent is as I can't seem to find any documentation about Samsung specific system functionality.

My objective is to create a tasker profile which toggles Power Saving mode when I turn the screen on and off, instead of using NFC to trigger this event.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the task in NFC Launcher, install Autoshortcut (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en-GB) and then you can call the NFC launcher task within Tasker via the Plugins>Autoshortcut>Configuration>Run Task.

I just got my unrooted Note 2 setup to disable powersaving when on USB power and enable it again when I unplug it :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make *Tasker* work with NFC, you can use a NFC Plugin: [Locale NFC Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.badaccess.locale.nfc) does work with Tasker (according to the app description, and as generally *Locale* plugins do work with *Tasker*), and should enable you to do what you've described.

Comment: Hi Izzy, I'm not trying to get Tasker to work with NFC, I'm trying to get Tasker to execute something that the NFC Task Launcher can do, which Tasker cannot do.

Comment: Sorry I'll be a bit more specific, so NFC Task Launcher allows me to turn Samsung's power saving mode on and off, but only if I use bluetooth, Wifi or NFC to trigger it. For me, I would like to toggle power saving mode but when the screen turns on and off

Comment: You might want to update your question to make that clear :) So the problem is *Tasker* not being able to toggle that power saving mode? Maybe it can with the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) plugin (I cannot test, don't have that device, so it's just a guess)? If you want that app directly supported by *Tasker*, you might want to ask the dev to implement a specific *Tasker* plugin.

Comment: Secure Settings might be able to do it but I don't want to root my phone. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Secure Settings does not require root for all actions. Best I can tell, the [Enable or Disable Samsung Modes](http://securesettings.intangibleobject.com/home) action only requires a Samsung ROM (which you have if you have a stock Samsung phone).